# Plotting (x,y) coordinates over timestamp values

Tags: r, visualization

I have movement data (x,y) coordinates with corresponding timestamp values and I need to plot this in R. The `gvisMotionChart()` and other `googleVis` offerings don't seem to accept timestamp values. Any ideas on the relevant R package that can be used for visualizing this movement data over time? Sample data as follows:

```
timestamp                    x    y
Feb 17, 2013 8:33:24 PM.000  724 414
Feb 17, 2013 8:34:24 PM.000  398 769
Feb 17, 2013 8:43:27 PM.000  398 769
Feb 17, 2013 8:44:15 PM.000  637 1083
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Reading the documentation of `gvisMotionChart` (which I have never used myself) one learns that it accepts numeric time values, but also needs an ID column. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="timestamp; x; y
Feb 17, 2013 8:33:24 PM.000; 724; 414
Feb 17, 2013 8:34:24 PM.000; 398; 769
Feb 17, 2013 8:43:27 PM.000; 398; 769
Feb 17, 2013 8:44:15 PM.000; 637; 1083",
header=TRUE,sep=";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF$timestamp <- as.numeric(strptime(DF$timestamp,
                                    "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p.000",tz="GMT"))
DF$timestamp <- DF$timestamp-min(DF$timestamp)
DF$ID <- 1


library(googleVis)
M1 <- gvisMotionChart(DF, idvar="ID", timevar="timestamp",xvar="x", yvar="y")
plot(M1)
```